# Why is my Windows PowerShell script not running?

Tags: windows, powershell-ise

I need to submit this script for a college assignment. We are supposed to write a script that searches for, and list files that have the .doc, .docx, .xls, and .xlsx extension. But, my script is not doing what it should do. Could someone please help me? I need to submit it by tomorrow. This is the script that I typed.

```
$Search = "C:\"
$Outfile = "C:\temp\report.csv"
$Files = Dir $Search -Recurse -Include *doc, *.docx, *.xls, *.xlsx -EA SilentlyContinue
Select-Object Length, name, Fullname, extension | Sort-Object extension

$Files | Export-Csv $Outfile -NoTypeInformation

$Files | Group extension -NoElement | % { $Ext = $_.Name;$_ | Select @{N="Extension";E={$_.Name}}, Count,@{N="SizeMB"
                                        E={"{0:N2}" -f (($Files | ?{$_.Extension -eq $Ext} | Measure Length -Sum).Sum /1MB)}}} |
                                        ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $Outfile -Append -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: Well at least you’re honest. :P // You’re saying it doesn’t do what you want, but what *is* it doing? Also, you *really* need some intermediate variables, this code is very hard to read.

Comment: I suggest that for coding questions, StackOverflow.com may be more appropriate.  Furthermore, it would be good to isolate the question... narrowing it down a little.  Can you identify what parts work well?  (Assigning more variables, and printing results, can help with that tremendously.)